# How can I know if some other user of the app is close to me?

Tags: android

I have used a broadcast receiver but I couldn't get the location of any user that comes in proximity of 1 km.I can't understand what is wrong here.
The code for receiver is . . .

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class ProximityReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

LocationManager locationManager;
double latitude, longitude;
Location location;
Context context;
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE = 1000;
private static final long MIN_TIME = 6000;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 1000;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    Log.d("Proximity Reciever", "Inside Reciever");

    String k = LocationManager.KEY_LOCATION_CHANGED;

    // Key for determining whether user is leaving or entering

    this.context = context;
    boolean state = intent.getBooleanExtra(k, false);
    //Gives whether the user is entering or leaving in boolean form

    try {
        Log.d("ProxyReceiver_State", "Got the state:" + state);

        if (state) {
            // Call the Notification Service or anything else that you would like to do here
            Log.d("ProxyRe_State_true", "Someone Came in . . ");

            Toast.makeText(context, "Welcome to my Area", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            //Other custom Notification
            Toast.makeText(context, "Thank you for visiting my Area,come back again !!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Proxy_Receiver", String.valueOf(e));
    }
}
}
```

And the code for the activity which uses this receiver is :

```
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class Proxy extends AppCompatActivity {

private GPS_Tracker gps_tracker;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private double lat = 0.0, long1 = 0.0;    //Defining Latitude & Longitude
float radius = 1000.0f;//in metres
private ProximityReciever reciever;

@SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_proxy);

    //reciever = new ProximityReciever();

    //GPS tracker to know your current location . . ..
    //i have created another class for this 
    try {
        gps_tracker = new GPS_Tracker(Proxy.this);
        Log.d("Can Get Location:", String.valueOf(gps_tracker.canGetLocation()));
        if (gps_tracker.canGetLocation()) {
            lat = gps_tracker.getLatitude();
            long1 = gps_tracker.getLongitude();
            Log.d("Proxy_MyLocation", "Latitude: " + lat + "Longitude: " + long1);
            Toast.makeText(this, "My Location: Latitude: " + lat + " Longitude: " + long1, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            gps_tracker.showSettingAlert();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Proxy_Exception", String.valueOf(e));
    }

    //tryinh out things with Proxiity Reciever. . . .
    //calling it and which detects the other users . . . .
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        Log.d("Proxy_Manager", "Getting Location manager and sending intent");

        //Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.hp.proximityalert");
        Intent intent = new Intent("com.example.hp.proximityalert.ProximityAlert");

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);
        //PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 1, intent, 0);

        locationManager.addProximityAlert(lat, long1, radius, -1, pi);

        Log.d("Proxy_Manager", "Added PRoxy Alert");

        reciever = new ProximityReciever();

        //Receive something from the other activity . . .
        IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter("com.example.hp.proximityalert.ProximityAlert");
        //
        Log.d("Proxy_Manager", "Intent Filter . . . .");
        //
        intentFilter.setPriority(999);

        //this.registerReceiver(reciever, intentFilter);
        registerReceiver(reciever, intentFilter);

        Log.d("Proxy_Manager", "Receiver registered . . .");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.d("Proxy_Proxy_error", String.valueOf(e));
    }

  }
}
```

I have used my current location and created a proximity of 1 km radius around my location to detect if any user of the same app comes in my proximity . . . 
But I cannot find other users even in same room

Any idea how to detect the nearby user which also uses the same app can be detected,would be appreciated . . .

Comment: That's not at all how a broadcast receiver works....

Comment: To detect the nearby user, you must create a server and an middle app that can track with. For example: 1st device sends current position to the server, then 2nd device gets list of devices from the server, finally using google map to calculate distance between 1st and 2nd device's position. Broadcast receiver will being run continuously as 2nd device's role.

Comment: can this thing be done using firebase ?